# What is the meaning of "d'abaque"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have been doing some French technical translations with the help of web translators and came across a term "d'abaque", which the translators translate as "abacus".  This didn't make sense so I queried and I was told it means "a measure based on past experience".

For instance:

- a job takes two weeks, and x tons of concrete "d'abaque"
- the installation will need 5 people and cost $10K "d'abaque"

Is there an English equivalent for "d'abaque".

Comment: Going by past experience, this job will take two weeks, and require x tons of concrete.

Comment: It may just mean "an approximate calculation, derived from tables".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about translation from French.

Comment: I should imagine that if it's "of the abacus" then it's an alternative to *calculé*. It's still off-topic.

Comment: Sounds like it could be translated as "estimated" or maybe "approximately", though the English term likely would need to be in parentheses or repositioned in the sentence.

Comment: Agree with @1006a.  "The estimate for the job is two weeks, X tons of concrete and N dollars."   (Plan on its taking at least twice as long.)